# How to copy libraries a dynamically linked program is built against?

Tags: compiling, dynamic-linking

Recently, I've been into compiling software and distributing it. Last time I did it, I did so by building my program and running ldd on it to get all of the libraries it was linked against. I got the path of the library (like say `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6`) and I copied and pasted it from my system. It worked great, but manually copying and pasting each library seemed repetitive. Is there a way that I can just get a list of the paths to the libraries alone (without all of the `libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f1dc3333000)`) so I can copy them and distribute them with my build?

Comment: Search for "cross compilation" `apt-cache search cross-compilation` and `apt-cache search binutils`. With a cross-compilation environment set up, the correct compiler, correct linker correct libraries are taken care of automagically.

Comment: What are you trying to distributed exactly? Why don't you build a proper package of your project and distribute it in a PPA or such?

Comment: @dobey I am just building some software to distribute to some friends who all use different GNU/Linux distros. That's why I want to bundle the libraries: to make it more cross-platform. Ideally, I want to bundle every library the program is linked against, including libc. As I've previously said, I've done this before my manually copying and pasting each library one at a time and it worked out wonderfully. I just want to know if there is some command I can run to automate the process.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste no, bundling libraries is not how you do it. That is what the package manager is for.

Comment: @muru Not if they use distros that use different package managers on different operating systems (one of the friends I'm distributing this to uses Fedora) that have different versions of the libraries.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste again: That's what the package manager is for.

Comment: @FuzzyToothpaste if the package manager absolutely allows only one version of a library, *then* you use static linking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At that point, you are basically building a tarball of an entire Linux distribution. Depending on the libraries you link to, simply including the dynamic library itself may not be enough (some libraries depend on plug-in modules, and other external files, which are not installed in the same locations, as the same versions, across all distributions of Linux).

There are a few options to deal with these differences:

- Distribute the source code of your program and let the people whom you are distributing to, so that the users my compile it themselves, on their distribution of choice.
- Re-compile a version of your program for every different version of every different distribution of Linux you wish to support, and distribute your program in packages for those distributions and versions.
- Compile your application by using static linking, rather than dynamic linking. If you link to libraries that depend on external modules or files though, this can still be problematic.
- Distribute a VM image of a specific Linux distribution which you wish to support, that is a minimal install, and has your program installed by default, to provide a full environment to run it in.

Comment: "Distribute a VM image" ... Docker!

Answer (score 1):

I have it figured out (mostly).

Let's suppose that the program I built that I plan to distribute is located at /bin/bash. I could create a new directory and run the following command:
`cp $(ldd /bin/bash) ./`

This will give some error messages, but they can be ignored.